# php javascript url encoding

Tags: php, javascript, urlencode

I have a html text. I had encoded it in php using urlencode function.
I want to decode that text in the javascript. 
when i use unescape function in javascript it replaces all the special characters back but sapce is replaced by '+'. how can i do it correctly so that  space is replaced as space itself???

Comment: Checkout my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54121513/10539212). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using rawurlencode instead - urlencode does some things differently for "historical" reasons.

See http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php for more information.

Answer (score 53):

PHP rawUrlEncode() == JavaScript encodeURIComponent()

PHP rawUrlDecode() == JavaScript decodeURIComponent()

Comment: be ware that php urlencode is not compatible with javascript so u should use rawUrlEncode instead

Comment: Working for me

    (((PHP)))
    $msg = array();
    $msg['adds'] = rawUrlEncode($complexAddsWithHTMLMarkup);
    echo json_encode($msg);

    ......(((jQuery ajax dataType json)))
    decodeURIComponent(msg.adds);

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is wrong for some characters. In php `rawurlencode(")") == "%29"` while in javascript `encodeURIComponent(")") == ")"`.

Comment: @RégisB. To comply to RFC 3986 there is a fix on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). To the bottom there is a function called `fixedEncodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 4):

Parenthesis are exceptions to all of what is said in this post.

geek mode on :

**false**

```
PHP rawUrlEncode() !== JavaScript encodeURIComponent()
```

**but true**

```
PHP rawUrlEncode() == JavaScript encodeURIComponent()
```

In other words, there are many special characters that aren't treated as safe in rawurlencode when they are in encodeURIComponent.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
return decodeURIComponent((str + '').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
```

Source: http://phpjs.org/functions/urldecode:572

Comment: I think it should be `replace(/\+/g, ' '))`

Answer (score 0):

PHP `rawUrlEncode` with JS `unescape` (deprecated but working)

For me `decodeURIComponent` throw errors sometimes.