# encode url with javascript, decode with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, url, encode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php javascript url encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105434/php-javascript-url-encoding)

if I encode a url with javascript's encodeURI(), will I be able to use PHP's url_decode to decode it without any possibility of error?

similar question for the other direction (encode with url_encode() in PHP, decode with javascript)

Comment: Not a duplicate of 1105434 - It's the opposite direction (as pointed out by the OP)

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to pass a URI as a parameter, you'll probably want to use Javascript's encodeURLComponent() method. If I remember right, PHP's urlencode/urldecode methods expect all non-alphanumeric characters to be encoded (which Javascript's encodeURI does not seem to do).

For more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp
https://www.php.net/urlencode
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php