# JavaScript encodeURIComponent vs PHP ulrencode

Tags: php, javascript, urlencode

The difference between them is that the PHP's `urlencode` encodes spaces with `+` instead of `%20`?

What are the functions that do the same thing for both the languages?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `rawurlencode` instead of `urlencode` in PHP.

Comment: Is that really the case though? PHP docs are confusing me... it says `rawurlencode` is for /.../ and `urlencode` is for /?....

Comment: This could be useful: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/. It's an online tool that lets you see how each function in both languages encode a URI. `rawurlencode` and `encodeURIComponent` produced the same output.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this link at php's own documention [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

`rawurlencode` will do the trick, the link is for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Actually even with JavaScript encodeURIComponent and PHP rawurlencode, they are not exactly the same too, for instance the '(' character, JavaScript encodeURIComponent will not convert it however PHP rawurlencode will convert it to %28. After some experiments and tips from others such as this question [another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663857/explanation-requested-for-fixedencodeuricomponent).

I found the ultimate solution [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

All you need to do is use the add following code

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
        return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    });
}
```

They will be **EXACTLY** the same now, for example

```
fixedEncodeURIComponent(yourUrl) (JavaScript) = (PHP) rawurlencode(yourUrl)
```

no problem with decode, you can use decodeURIComponent() for JavaScript and rawurldecode for PHP

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem between `rawurlencode()` and `encodeURIComponent()`.  The difference for me was that I didn't discover the issue until using `encodeURIComponent()` in numerous source files, so going back to fix and change them all and then re-test everything was not an option.

Fortunately, JS gives you the ability to "hijack" built-in functions by assigning the same name to a new function. You can thus change the behavior of `encodeURIComponent()` with a very slight modification to Phantom1412's code, and without having to recode anything.

Just put this script in your page before your code makes any calls to `encodeURIComponent()`:

```js
var encodeURIComponentOld = encodeURIComponent;
encodeURIComponent = function(str) {
    return encodeURIComponentOld(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
         return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    });
};
```